Sending to linux serial tty from embedded system too fast
I use an embedded computer to send data to a Linux serial port for transfer to a remote server. The terminal mode is "none". After my embedded system logs in, it sends data for example,
printf "123456789ABCDEF" | netcat -u -q 5 dest_addr dest_port

The data arrives at the remote server correctly, but the Linux terminal echos back repeated fragments of the data and lots of \08
Using the above case as a truncated example (actual data is 200 bytes), what is echoed back to my embedded system looks like this:
user@mymachine:~$ printf 1234  
<4567  
\08\08\0889ABC  
\08\08\08\08  
<CDEF  
netcat -u -q 5  
\08\08\08dest_addr dest_port
user@mymachine:~$  

I don't want my embedded system to get this unnecessary reply. And why is the Linux terminal echoing back fragments of the command anyway?
============ New info ==============
The \08 are backspaces that follow spaces. The terminal is backspacing over erroneous spaces it also sent sent back.
The echoed data is sent in overlapping fragments. And if I edit out the repeated bytes echoed back, the data is exactly what I sent. Why is it doing this?

The backspaces as well as
user@mymachine:~$ printf 1234  
<4567  

...looks a lot like the output Bash/Readline would produce, when it receives input that is too wide for (its view of) the terminal.
The Bash shell, meant for interactive use, has line editing as a built-in feature. Its Readline component supports cursor movement through the entire input, including when the input is long enough that it would wrap into multiple lines; to achieve this, Readline will 1) use remote echo, and 2) output terminal control characters (e.g. VT220 cursor movement) to let the user move around using arrow-keys.
Setting the remote terminal emulation mode to 'dumb' tells Readline that VT cursor movement is unavailable, but does not disable the line-editing feature in general; it only makes Readline fall back to dumb-terminal compatible behavior, in which the entire input is echoed as a single line (because the terminal can't do cursor movement), and the prompt line is "refreshed" by backspacing over it (as even dumb terminals support backspacing, generally).
For example, if you run TERM=dumb bash locally, then start entering a long command, at first you will see:
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ [grawity@frost ~]$ aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb cccccccccc█     │
│                                                                            │
│                                                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

But as the command gets longer and about to exceed the width of the terminal, Bash will backspace over the line and re-echo it again, so that the user will see:
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ <aaaaaa bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb ccccccccccccccccc ddddddddddddd█              │
│                                                                            │
│                                                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

It does this instead of relying on terminal-side local echo, as the latter (at least with Linux) doesn't allow the user to backspace into the previous line, whereas Bash's custom rendering does. Compare this with e.g. dash which relies on "cooked" mode line-by-line reading, and in which, once your input wraps into the second line, you can no longer backspace across the line boundary.
The "width" of the terminal defaults to 80 unless changed by stty size or some similar tool (e.g. a commonly used 'resize' tool queries it using VT control codes and updates the tty parameters accordingly).
If you want to avoid this – while still continuing to automate an interactive shell login, for some reason – the easiest option is to (immediately after logging in) start a new shell that doesn't use such line editing, e.g. send bash --noediting\n or dash\n as your first command. (Or, if you can, permanently chsh the remote user's login shell to /bin/dash.)
(Alternatively: Disable the regular getty and set up an IP/PPP link over the serial line, then perform your automation via SSH or some other TCP protocol.)

This. You don't even need to set up a PPP link; you could replace the login shell of the account used for this with a simple script that disables echoing with stty -echo -echoe -echok, reads the first line from the serial port and interprets it as the IP address and port to connect to, and passes the rest to netcat. If the serial port is to be dedicated to this purpose, you could even replace the serial port getty with such a script, eliminating the need to login in the first place.

telcoM that works perfectly. I previously read the man page on stty but I didn't just try that. SOLVED

u1686_grawity that works perfectly. Thank for chiming in here. Problem SOLVED.

You're not configuring your serial port correctly. The \08 signifies a byte with only the fourth bit set – typical for combinations of incorrect (typically: too high) baud rate and incorrect framing set.
So, configure your serial port correctly. We don't know your hardware and hence can't help you with that. It's something you can only find out from documentation or trial and error (unless you have a device with better baudrate autodetection at hand, which doesn't seem to be the case).
The terminal emulator you're using might be configured for echoing transmitted things back locally. You don't specify how you set up that.

The baud rate is correct. As I wrote above the data arrives at the server correct.
└─# dmesg | grep tty  

[    0.063173] printk: legacy console [tty0] enabled  

[    0.784439] 00:06: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4, base_baud = 115200) is a 16550


Serial port setup:
systemctl start serial=getty@ttyS0.service

it really doesn't seem to be correct, regardless of what you say.

Something is not set right. There is more to serial communication than the hardware settings of the serial port. Hopefully someone will offer some possible causes that I can look into.

nobody can. You will have to figure this out. A serial port doesn't have that many settings that are relevant; in fact, I listed both.

This has nothing do do with the serial port. The serial port emulation was set to "none." The same as when setting the serial port to "dumb." If I set the serial port to any other type the problem goes away but then I have a bunch of formatting and control characters the terminal emulator sends to my embedded system. So I have to choose one or the other.
Also when serial port settings are mismatched, the result is a bunch of garbage bytes. An improperly setup serial port cannot convert readable text into a series of backspaces.

I come here looking for advice and I end up educating someone else instead.

What is the output of stty -a?

stty -a
speed 115200 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = ;
eol2 = ; swtch = ; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ; discard = ; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 hupcl -cstopb cread clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
(continued below due to length)

isig icanon -iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc

And the data being sent is ASCII HEX, nothing below 0x20 (space).

what program is listening on UDP port dest_port on the destination computer (with IP address dest_addr)? Try printf "stty -a\\n" | netcat -u -q 5 dest_addr dest_port on the embedded system after logging in to the remote. Also you say nothing below 0x20 (space) but what about newline or carriage return? are those sent?

Do you have access to pv?
printf "123456789ABCDEF" | dd bs=1 | pv -L 5 > | netcat -u -q 5 dest_addr dest_port

Use dd to split into single characters, and then pv -L to limit the rate to 5 bytes per second.
(Or is that 5 _ characters_ per second? I guess that depends on how unicode-aware the tools are. I have no idea.)
I have successfully used tricks like this to debug faulty transceivers etc.
